# Is there a reference to the <html> root element from the window object?

Tags: html, dom

After reading the [MDN Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) about the `window.innerHeight`, I want to use the `<html>` elements `clientHeight` property in some of my tests, as it is "[the height of the window minus its horizontal scroll bar and any borders](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight#usage_notes)".

So I need a reference to the `<html>` element.

After examining the window object and the document object, the only way to obtain this reference is to query the dom. For example like this: `const htmlElement = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];`

I wonder if there is a better option? Maybe something simple like `document.htmlElement`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is

```
document.documentElement
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for - thank you!